# Why do I get a seg fault? I want to put a char array pointer inside a struct

Tags: segmentation-fault

consider the fallowing code:

```
typedef struct port * pport;

struct port
{
  int a;
  int b;
  pport next;
  pport prev;
  char * port;
};

void addNewport(pport head)
{
  pport newPort = (pport)malloc(sizeof(pport*));
  newPort->prev=temp;
  head->next=newPort;
}

int main()
{
  pport head = (pport)malloc(sizeof(pport*));
  addNewport(head);
}
```

This will result in seg fault if try to add a new port via a subroutine, but if I perform it the main, no seg fault will appear.  Why is that?

Comment: temp isnt defined anywhere that i can see...

Comment: Also, you're malloc'ing memory the size of a pointer, not the struct.

Comment: I think myrkos hit the nail on the head, you're reading memory you're not allowed to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 malloc(sizeof(pport*))
```

with

```
 malloc(sizeof(struct port))
```

because you don't want to allocate memory for a pointer, rather for the struct.