# Seg Fault when copying a pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

How come the following code result in seg fault?  Basically after I copy the head pointer to temp, the head pointer gone.

```
typedef struct address * paddress; // defines struct pointer

void addAddressToList(paddress head, int addr[])
{
  if (head == NULL) {
    //head->addrArray = addr; // if list is initially empty
  } else {
    paddress temp;
    temp = head;
    while (temp->right != NULL) {
      temp = temp->right;  // go to end of the list
    }
    paddress newAddress = (paddress)malloc(sizeof(paddress*));
    newAddress->intAddr = addr;
    newAddress->right = NULL;    
    newAddress->left = temp;  // connect the new address
    temp->right = newAddress;
  }
}

main() {
  paddress addressListHead;
  addressListHead = (paddress)malloc(sizeof(paddress*));
  int intAddr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
  char hexAddr1[] = "123456";
  int intAddr2[] = {16,14,13,12,11};
  char hexAddr2[] = "fedcb";

  addressListHead->intAddr = intAddr1;
  addressListHead->hexAddr = hexAddr1;
  addAddressToList(addressListHead, intAddr2);
}
```

Comment: Add return type to `main`. Also add the language tag when you post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one problem in your code.

Firstly, the usual advice: stop using `sizeof` with type names (as much as possible). Use `sizeof` with *expressions*, not types. Type names belong in declarations and nowhere else.

Your problem with memory allocation could have been prevented if you used this `malloc` idiom

```
T *p = malloc(n * sizeof *p);
```

i.e. `sizeof` should be applied to `*p`, where `p` is the pointer to the array you are allocating and `n` is the total number of elements in that array. That way you never have to guess what type name you should specify under `sizeof` (an that way your code becomes type-independent).

In your case you are allocating just one object, so the code should look as

```
paddress newAddress = malloc(sizeof *newAddress);
```

(And don't cast the result of `malloc` - there's absolutely no point in doing that).

Secondly, when you the head element of the list, you need to initialize all the fields. Yet you never initialize `right` (or `left`) in the head element. Hence the crash even when the correct amount of memory is allocated.

Answer (score 2):

```
paddress addressListHead;
addressListHead = (paddress)malloc(sizeof(paddress*));
```

It seems to get rid of the compilation error, you have type casted what malloc is returning to `paddress`. `addressListHead` is a pointer, which means it can hold the address of an object but **not** the address of a pointer. The malloc here statement doesn't create an object. You need to change this -

```
addressListHead = (paddress)malloc(sizeof(paddress*));
```

to

```
addressListHead = (paddress)malloc(sizeof(struct address));
```

in `main` and `addAddressToList` functions.

Segmentation fault :

```
else {
  paddress temp;
  temp = head;
  while (temp->right != NULL) {
    temp = temp->right;  // go to end of the list
}
```

I understand `paddress::right` is a pointer with the fact you are comparing it to **NULL**. But what is `temp::right` is initialized to. It is pointing to some garbage address and so you **cannot** ask for it to compare with **NULL**. Make it point to a valid memory location.

Answer (score 1):

In main(), you want

```
addressListHead = (paddress)malloc(sizeof(address));
```

That makes sure you get enough bytes to hold an address.

Comment: no that still produces a seg fault, the seg fault results right after the temp = head assignment

Comment: @Ronnie Slack: That simply means that your code has more than one problem. You forgot to properly initialize your list head.

Answer (score 0):

First error:

```
addressListHead = (paddress)malloc(sizeof(paddress*));
```

paddress* means a pointer to paddress which itself is a pointer to struct address. Hence paddress* is a pointer to a pointer to struct address. You would want to do:

```
addressListHead = (paddress)malloc(sizeof(struct address));
```

Also, I see that you made a similar mistake yesterday. [Why do I get a seg fault? I want to put a char array pointer inside a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623994/why-do-i-get-a-seg-fault-i-want-to-put-a-char-array-pointer-inside-a-struct)

It's important to understand the concept of pointers properly. I would definitely recommend you to go through some tutorials on pointers. If you need help with that, let me know.

Comment: ...Meaning that this poster is apparently using SO to debug his code. He makes the suggested corrections purely mechanically, without caring to understand their meaning. Then he posts the next piece of code for us to debug, which can easily contain errors of exactly the same nature as in the previous piece of code.